# What is the concept of an Assembly in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm new to .NET and am having trouble understanding the concept of an Assembly - what is an Assembly? What do people mean when they say 'copy the assembly...'? What is the purpose of AssemblyInfo.cs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> what is an Assembly?

A physical unit of deployment.

> What do people mean when they say 'copy the assembly...'?

Most assemblies are XCopy deployable - meaning you can just file copy them to their destination.

> What is the purpose of AssemblyInfo.cs?

It sets Assembly level metadata. Things like version number, copyright notices, COM interop rules, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Its roughly analogous to a [DLL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_link_library) or an [EXE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable).

Assemblies are the building blocks of .NET Framework applications; they form the fundamental unit of deployment, version control, reuse, activation scoping, and security permissions. An assembly is a collection of types and resources that are built to work together and form a logical unit of functionality. An assembly provides the common language runtime with the information it needs to be aware of type implementations. To the runtime, a type does not exist outside the context of an assembly.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hk5f40ct%28VS.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 4):

> a reusable, versionable, and
>   self-describing building block of a
>   common language runtime application.

Best to go to the creator's website and do a search:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hk5f40ct(VS.71).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.aspx

It's reusable, meaning you can duplicate it and use it in conjunction with other applications/assemblies that reference it.

It's versionable, meaning you can have many different versions of the same assembly and other applications/assemblies can reference any of those versions, or just the newest one.

It's self-describing, meaning it projects an interface to the world for other applications/assemblies to consume.

AssemblyInfo.cs is just a file where you can go edit various descriptors about your assembly. For instance the title, description, or the version number.

Answer (score 2):

Assembly = .net DLL or EXE;  AssemblyInfo.cs is the conventional place to put the values that lived in the Version resource of a native executable.

Answer (score 2):

The AssemblyInfo.cs contains attributes for the assembly (defined in all the other answers). Attributes for example are version info.